# Can't reload Table View in tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, reloaddata

Hi I have a tab tab controller and my first tab includes a view with:

- 3 text fields
- a submit button
- a tableView

Once I fill in the text fields I click submit and it adds the information to my managedObjectContext which is an sqlite database (CoreData).

As soon as I click submit I want the tableView to reload to include the added object. Currently my tableView will display the data in the database but it will only add the new row when I stop and re-run the simulator

This is the code for when the add button is tapped, it is here that I can't get the reload tableView working because it says tableView is an undeclared identifier, what have i missed?

```
-(IBAction)addButtonTapped:(id)sender {
NSLog (@"Add Button Tapped");
NSLog(@"Adding %@ units of item code %@ at $%@ each",quantityTextField.text,productTextField.text,priceTextField.text);


Products_MarketAppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
NSManagedObject* newProduct;
newProduct = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[newProduct setValue:productTextField.text forKey:@"itemCode"];
[newProduct setValue:quantityTextField.text forKey:@"quantity"];
[newProduct setValue:priceTextField.text forKey:@"price"];

if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges]) 
    NSLog(@"Managed Object Changed");

NSError* error;
[managedObjectContext save:&error];

// Insert Reload Table Code Here
// ** I have tried the following and it gives an error "Use of undeclared identifier 'tableView'"
//[tableView reloadData];
//[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

As you can see below I have added the UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource in the header file. I have also hooked up the tableview in IB so that the delegate and datasource connections are linked to file's owner.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
<UIApplicationDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

{
IBOutlet UITextField *productTextField;
IBOutlet UITextField *quantityTextField;
IBOutlet UITextField *priceTextField;

NSMutableArray *items;
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

-(IBAction)addButtonTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

This is the code to fill the tableView which works correctly

```
#pragma mark TableView
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil){   
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
}

// Configure the cell
Product* productItem =[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ x %@ @ $%@",productItem.quantity,productItem.itemCode,productItem.price];

return cell;  
}
```

I have searched for answers on this site and on others but I must be doing something different and the solutions aren't helping me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your UIViewController does not currently have an instance variable pointing to your tableview.  Set one up:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

Remember to synthesize this in your .m

```
@synthesize myTableView;
```

Then in your code you can call

```
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

You might have got confused by looking at code examples that use a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController.  The UITableViewController already has an instance variable called tableView, so your subclass wouldn't need it's own tableView instance variable declared.  But you're using a UIViewController, so you must declare a tableView instance variable.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I have made the changes you have suggested. This is actually something I previously tried and then removed because it still didn't do the trick. Is there anything else I can try? It gives no errors but the tableView stays the same. I'm not using a nav controller. The text fields, button and tableView are all on the same view, is this a problem?

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine to have the textfields, button and tableView on the same view.  Try putting some NSLog statements around to help debug.  Specifically, put one inside your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.  Eg   NSLog(@"I'm inside the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:");

Comment: Ok thanks great tip. I did as you suggested and it confirms that [self.myTableView reloadData] does not run any of the methods relating to the tableView. I have been looking at the documentation, since I am using NSFetchedResultsController should i be using _'- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.myTableView endUpdates];
}'_ and other methods to update changes in the table view?

Comment: I'm not apt with the NSFetchedResultsController class sorry.  -endUpdates would only be used after a call to -beginUpdates.  You could use those if you didn't want the entire table to be reloaded (instead of calling -reloadData).  Read up about those before using them.    I'd suggest you focus on finding out why your tableView dataSource methods aren't being called with you call reloadData.  Try to isolate the issues in you code and debug each on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @MattyG for all your help. At first I wasn't sure if I was going against the norm and thats why it wasn't working.

I ended up solving the problem due to your suggestions & it works perfectly! I used the debugger and found that that although we had created a property for the table I had not created an IBOutlet and linked it in my nib file with:

```
IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

I guess this meant that I was telling myTableView to reload but it wasn't hooked up to my table and thus couldn't use the datasource methods.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.  Nice work on tracking down the outlet omission.  I forgot you might be using interface builder instead of initializing your tableview in code.  I've added IBOutlet to my answer for other peoples' future reference.  Cheers, Matty